# Font Awesome 5, Why the instagram icon is missing?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

why there is no instagram icon here

```css
.share{
display:inline-block;
color:#0099cc;
font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-facebook-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square share"></i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the version of the CDN to the lastest one. It was not there in 5.7 and was add starting from 5.12 (https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5121---2020-02-04)

> Added
>
> instagram-square icon FortAwesome/Font-Awesome#9223

```css
.share {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #0099cc;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-facebook-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square share"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `fa-instagram-square` isn't a part of your .css file.

Please use https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css that includes the fa-instagram-square icon.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-facebook-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square share"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the cdn version to the latest v5.15.1 since the instagram-square has been introduced in later versions.

```css
.share{
display:inline-block;
color:#0099cc;
font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-facebook-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-instagram-square share"></i>
<i class="fab fa-twitter-square share"></i>
```